# Getting Error while opening jfr file in JMC console

Tags: java, jmc, jfr

I'm getting too large recording error while trying to open my 60 MB jfr file in JMC console. Please help me on this.

Thank you

Comment: 60 MB is not a very large recording. i have opened recordings that are gigabytes. That said, if you have very little RAM on your machine it could be a problem. I think newer version of JMC and older JRockit versions will detect that the file is large and allow you select a subset of events.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to run JMC with more memory?

```
jmc -vmargs -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
```

The other solution is to split the jfr file into smaller chunks and open that chunks.

Comment: I could not run jmc with -vmargs , I have tried splitting the files but I couldnt able to do it

Comment: What happens when you run with -vmargs? That’s what I would recommend as well. Other option to do the same is to edit the JDK/lib/missioncontrol/jmc.ini file and add the -Xmx option there. (File located a bit differently on Mac)

Answer (score 1):

I came across [this page](http://hirt.se/blog/?p=663) which provides a simple tool for splitting overly large JFR files into smaller chunks.  The author works (or worked) at Oracle.

(But I can't find the source code, the JAR is not signed, and the download link is not even HTTPS protected.  Be careful what you download ... and all that.)